# Linq query not working but its equivalent SQL Server query is working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, datetime

Following SQL query works fine (Give expected results) in SQL Server.

```
SELECT * FROM ImportedReportDataCRR IRD 
INNER JOIN ImportedReport IR ON IRD.ImportedReportId = IR.Id
WHERE 
IR.StartDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '7/1/2022 12:00:00 AM') AND IR.EndDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '7/31/2022 11:59:59 PM')
```

But when I use equivalent Linq (C# / ASP.Net) its not working as expected (Empty result set returned).

My Linq statement is

```
var ImportedReportDataList = DbContext.ImportedReportDataCRRs.Where(w =>
                (w.ImportedReport.StartDate.Value >= StartDate && w.ImportedReport.EndDate.Value <= EndDate)).ToList();
```

-- Update Starts --

Linq converts into following SQL query

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].* 
    FROM  
    [dbo].[ImportedReportDataCRR] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ImportedReport] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ImportedReportId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    WHERE 
    ([Extent2].[StartDate] >= @p__linq__0) AND 
    ([Extent2].[EndDate] <= @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='2022-07-01 00:00:00.0010000',@p__linq__1='2022-07-31 23:59:59.9970000'
```

i.e. Linq is converting StartDate and EndDate into datetime2(7) which is creating issue.

-- Update Ends --

Variable StartDate = 7/1/2022 12:00:01 AM

Variable EndDate = 7/31/2022 11:59:59 PM

ImportedReport.StartDate = 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 (DB field value)

ImportedReport.EndDate = 2022-07-31 00:00:00.000 (DB field value)

Comment: That is the earliest possible time value for July 1st.

Comment: What to you mean by the start or end? A `datetime` value isn't a range, it's a point in time. `2022-07-01 00:00:00.000` represents **exactly** midnight on 01 July 2022, and nothing else. A day starts at midnight, and ends immediately *before* the next one starts (I intentionally don't give a time here as leap seconds exist), so midnight can't be the end of a day. Are you, perhaps, trying to use `BETWEEN` on date time values?

Comment: Post the comparison query.  Sounds like there's an issue in the query or you're interpreting the results incorrectly.

Comment: _"but a date comparison query I am using is making issue if I take this start of 1st of July 2022"_ - I'm guessing you're (ab)using `datetime` to represent dates (without time-of-day)? and/or you're using parameters or litrerals incorrectly typed - or you're inadvertently using an inclusive-upper-bound range predicate? Or you're using `BETWEEN`? (Fun fact: `DECLARE @dt datetime = '2022-08-10'` is **really** `2022-08-10 00:00:00`).

Comment: Quite simply, never try to find the _end_ of any period (whether it's a day, a month, a year, what have you). Because different data types change what it means, it's _always_ safer to perform range queries in the form `>= start of period` and `< start of _next_ period`. See all the links involving `BETWEEN` at [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates).

Comment: I have Edited my question and have included my queries. If somebody can help or should I post with Linq Tag ?

Comment: What is the type of `ImportedReport.StartDate` and `ImportedReport.EndDate` and your variables `StartDate` and `EndDate`?

Comment: @Schwern Nullable DateTime

Comment: @Gulfam What is the type of your variables `StartDate` and `EndDate`? What query is linq actually executing?

Comment: @Schwern StarteDate and EndDate are DateTime. And ImportedReport.StartDate, ImportedReport.EndDate are Nullable DateTime

Comment: `(w.EmployeeName.Trim().ToLower() == "test")` <-- This won't work either btw.

Comment: When I checked Linq converted query using Profile then Linq was converting DateTime to datetime2(7) which is creating issue. Don't know why this is happening, but I guess I need to compare date only and should truncate the time part.

Comment: [`datetime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) should still compare correctly with `datetime`: [demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6f107156874b82e85d1bb0d66bffbaa0). Would you post the generated query, please? Could you explain what is "not working as expected"? What do you expect? What if you remove the suspicious `w.EmployeeName.Trim().ToLower() == "test"`?

Comment: @Schwern Please check question now. I have included converted query and more details as well.

Comment: Thanks all, issue has been resolved. A millisecond was there in StartDate (Linq) which was creating problem. Its should had been 00:00:00.000 but it was 00:00:00.001. DateTim2(7) was not the issue @AaronBertrand . It was my mistake but I learned a lot from your replies about Date comparisons. Date comparison in SQL Server can be very tricky and unexpected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, don't try to simulate `BETWEEN` where you find the *end* of a date range. This is problematic because different data types consider the "end" of a period differently. In this case, much better to say "greater than or equal to the first of July, and *less than* the first of August." Also using non-regional and unambiguous date formats:

```
SELECT <cols>
FROM dbo.ImportedReportData AS IRD 
INNER JOIN dbo.ImportedReport AS IR ON IRD.ImportedReportId = IR.Id
WHERE IR.StartDate     >= '20220701'
  AND IR.EndDate       <  '20220801'
  AND IRD.EmployeeName =  'test';
```

Please read all of the links at [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates).

I suppose in Linq you could say:

```
&& w.ImportedReport.EndDate.Value 
   < { whatever you do in Linq to add a day to EndDate }
```

Comment: When I checked Linq converted query using Profile then Linq was converting DateTime to datetime2(7) which is creating issue. Don't know why this is happening, but I guess I need to compare date only and should truncate the time part.

Comment: Please check question now. I have included converted query and more details as well. The problem is that Linq return empty result set while SQL Server query return expected rows.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Bertrand , issue has been resolved. A millisecond was there in StartDate (Linq) which was creating problem. Its should had been 00:00:00.000 but it was 00:00:00.001. DateTim2(7) was not the issue . It was my mistake but I learned a lot from your replies about Date comparisons. Date comparison in SQL Server can be very tricky and unexpected.